# Should this Chinese power supply be earthed?

Tags: power-supply, grounding, safety

I recently bought a piece of equipment from China, and it came with a laptop-style power supply. I immediately opened the supply to check if it was electrically safe, because we all know how lax the Chinese can be with electrical safety.

The unit has an IEC C14 socket for mains 240V in; and a basic barrel connector for output. The output voltage is adjustable up to 24V.

The construction seems reasonable, with good separation between the high and low voltage sections of the PCB; although of course you can never tell how good the transformer is without destroying it (unless you have an expensive Megger lying around).

One thing I noticed though, was that the Earth pin on the C14 socket is unconnected. Shouldn't it be connected to the negative of the low-voltage output? **Would it be a good idea for me to add my own wire?**

[image: top of PCB]

[image: bottom of PCB]

[image: Y1]

[image: transformer, input side]

[image: transformer, output side]

Comment: Please show the markings of the capacitor labeled "Y1" on the PCB. It'd also be nice if you could show the transformer (large yellow component) from all angles.

Comment: Does the equipment have a metal case?

Comment: It's difficult to get a good picture of the output side of the transformer; but I got good images of the other side and the Y1 component (a MOV, right?)

Comment: The low-voltage equipment the supply is used for has a metal case, yes. Which is why I'm concerned.

Comment: "Y1" is a ``JY222M`` from JNC. I can't find a JNC datasheet for it, but https://www.tti.com/content/ttiinc/en/apps/part-search.html?q=jy222m is a distributor search for JY222M which finds _Safety Capacitors_. See also [What's the difference between these two capacitors "JNC-JN222M" and "222-1KV"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/240245/101063)

Answer (score 2):

There is no rule that a power supply with an Earth input pin must have the Earth pin connected to output negative.

The supplies with 2-prong inlet can't do that anyway.

And you might not even want to connect the output to be referenced to Earth, if a floating supply is what you need or want.

Many laptop power bricks have floating output, even if they use the Earth input pin for mains filtering.

Which this power supply clearly lacks, no mains input filter at all.

Depending on wattage, to pass certification in the western market, it might be required to have power factor correction. Also missing on this supply.

I would not modify the unit at all.

In some cases, if you import yourself some dodgy electronics, you might be considered as the importer and thus responsible for the safety of the products you import.

Comment: @SodAlmighty Well, your power supply is built that way. We can't say if it is up to local standards or not. And I did answer your questions. No, it should no be earthed, it is not built that way, it is a floating supply, which is better that supplies with earthed output. And no, you should not add your own wire, as the intention of that supply is to have floating output. It just does not use earth for input filtering which it is usually used for. It's basically identical to a power brick with 2-prong inlet. It might be a selling point to have earthed inlet even if unused.

Comment: The table saw has a metal frame. If the power supply fails, wouldn't it be safer if the [table saw] was earthed? Is there a good reason why adding an earth wire would be a bad idea? [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: The construction of this PSU is actually much better than what you often get on Aliexpress etc. It has a proper class-Y EMI cap and the transformer doesn't look to be absolute trash. I agree that it shouldn't be modified.

Comment: @SodAlmighty There are reasons you want a floating power supply. For example to avoid ground loops. Your laptop might also have a metal frame and yet your laptop power brick output isn't earthed, even if your brick inlet has and uses an earth connection. If you want an earthed table saw with any random power supply, you can always earth it separately. DC power supplies may or may not earth the output, so this isn't out of the ordinary. Only if the power supply catasteophically fails and connects mains live to output, then earthing the metal frame is useful. Or an RCD so grounding not needed.